# ActiveAdmin filters- find all with a blank field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have an ActiveAdmin filters menu for Users, with a bunch of them listed like so:

```
filter :id
filter :full_name
filter :age
filter :supervisor, collection: Supervisors.all
```

I want to query for all Users who's supervisor field is set to nil. How can I do this?

Comment: Why filter `:supervisor` at the first place if you want to query Users that does not have a supervisor(assumed your supervisor field is `supervisor_id`)?

Comment: I want users to be able to select either a specific supervisor, any supervisor or no supervisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` by itself doesn't allow you to search for blanks, I think you have to workaround by adding a ransacker to your User model:

```
ransacker :by_supervisor, formatter: proc{ |v|
  v=nil if v==0
  data = User.where(supervisor: v).ids
  data = data.present? ? data : nil
} do |parent|
  parent.table[:id]
end
```

and in the ActiveAdmin module instead of the normal filter

```
filter :supervisor, collection: [Supervisor.new(id: 0, name: 'None'), Supervisor.all].flatten
```

This provides a Supervisor with id=0 to allow searching for "no supervisors", id=0 is turned into nil by the ransacker